# Como recuperar/pegar o valor do atributo “unicodePwd” no Active Directory através de uma aplicação java

Tags: java, active-directory

Eu li diversos artigos aqui no *StackOverflow* sobre como obter o valor do atributo "unicodePwd" no AD (Active Directory), mas nenhum desses artigos me ajudaram nessa situação.

Bem, por que eu preciso dessa informação? Vou explicar:

Eu tenho aqui diversas rotinas java que unificam informações de usuários de diferentes sistemas um com o outro. Essas rotinas pegam as informações necessárias de um banco de dados principal Oracle e, então, introduz as informações em outros bancos de dados (Oracle e MySQL, basicamente).

Por exemplo: Tenho um sistema interno de nuvem privada que roda em um sistema operacional Linux CentOS e que tem seu seu próprio bando de dados MySQL. Para unificar as informações dos usuários, inclusive as senhas de acesso, eu pego as informações nesse banco de dados principal Oracle e as introduzo no banco de dados MySQL do sistema, para unificar os detalhes do usuário e as informações de login.

Como eu disse, tenho diversas rotinas que estão funcionando corretamente sem problemas, mas agora temos um novo desafio.

Preciso fazer a mesma unificação com os nossos usuários do AD (Active Directory), ou seja, preciso pegar as informações dos usuários no banco de dados principal Oracle, incluindo a senha, para introduzirmos nos mesmos usuários do AD.

Eu já consegui atualizar o campo da senha com sucesso em alguns usuários de teste no AD, mas eu não quero que a senha seja atualizada todas as vezes que essa rotina rodar, mas somente quando a senha for alterada no banco de dados principal Oracle.

Exemplo: Quando um usuário trocar a senha dele no banco de dados principal Oracle, a rotina java vai recolher todas as informações para introduzir no mesmo usuário, só que do AD. Para fazer isso apropriadamente, a rotina pega as mesmas informações no AD e, em seguida, compara as senhas (senha do Oracle e senha do AD) e, finalmente, se as senhas forem diferentes, a rotina vai atualizar a senha do AD usando a senha do Oracle, mas se as senhas forem iguais, a rotina não vai fazer nada.

Por isso que preciso recuperar/pegar o valor do atributo "unicodePwd" no Active Directory.

Segue parte do código:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class ldapQuery {        

    String distinguishedName = "";
    String department = "";
    String physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "";
    String telephoneNumber = "";
    String mobile = "";
    String title = "";
    String sAMAccountName = "";
    String unicodePwd = "";

    public ldapQuery(String mail) {

        try {
            final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            final String adminName = "CN=MY DOMAIN ADMIN,CN=MY DOMAIN ADMIN FOLDER LOCALIZATION,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN";
            final String adminPasswd = "MY DOMAIN ADMIN PASSWORD";
            final String ldapUrl = "ldaps://MY ACTIVE DIRECTORY SERVER:636";
            final String factory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
            final String authType = "simple";
            final String protocol = "ssl";
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, factory);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authType);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPasswd); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);     
            DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext (env,null);

            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            String returnedAtts[] = {"sAMAccountName", "distinguishedName","department", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "telephoneNumber", "mobile", "title", "unicodePwd"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=" + mail +"))";
            String searchBase = "DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN";
            int totalResults = 0;
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer =ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                totalResults++; 
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

                if (attrs != null) {

                    distinguishedName = (String) attrs.get("distinguishedName").get();
                    department = (String) attrs.get("department").get();
                    physicalDeliveryOfficeName = (String) attrs.get("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").get();
                    telephoneNumber = (String) attrs.get("telephoneNumber").get();
                    mobile = (String) attrs.get("mobile").get();
                    title = (String) attrs.get("title").get();
                    sAMAccountName = (String) attrs.get("sAMAccountName").get();

                    Attribute passwd = attrs.get("unicodePwd");
                    unicodePwd = unicodePwd + passwd;

                    if (department == null) {
                        department = "";
                    }

                    if (physicalDeliveryOfficeName == null) {
                        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "";
                    }

                    if (telephoneNumber == null) {
                        telephoneNumber = "";
                    }

                   if (mobile == null) {
                        mobile = "";
                    }

                    if (title == null) {
                        title = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (NamingException e){
            System.err.println("FAIL MESSAGE: " + e);
        }
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultDistinguishedName() {
        return distinguishedName;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName() {
        return physicalDeliveryOfficeName;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultTelephoneNumber() {
        return telephoneNumber;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultUnicodePwd() {
        return unicodePwd;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultSAMAccountName() {
        return sAMAccountName;
    }
}
```

Depois de rodar esse código, todas as variáveis retornaram os valores corretos, menos a variável "unicodePwd", que retornou "null", mesmo que o usuário em questão tenha uma senha válida.

Eu sei a respeito do negócio do byte UTF-16LE e que o campo "unicodePwd" no Active Directory é criptografado, mas, como expliquei antes, eu preciso que essa informação seja retornada descriptografada numa variável String.

Alguma ideia?